# Which windows should be shown in Windows taskbar for a program?

Tags: wpf, windows, taskbar

Are there any guidelines to this? WPF windows are shown in taskbar by default. You must excplicitly set them not be shown there by

```
ShowInTaskbar = False
```

However it seems that many Microsoft programs seem to have only main window in taskbar.

Comment: close vote? why there's never explanation? i would never downvote somebody back or anything like that if he/she would explain his/hers close/down-votes? instead i would be happy to understand the mind of this kind of people to avoid these situations in future.

Comment: "primarily opinion"-based? that's just ridiculous. there could easily be guidelines to this. With this logic, coding style guides are opinion based.

Comment: Its intention is give the user an easy way to re-activate the app.  More than one button rarely makes sense, pick a window in your UI that ought to move back into the foreground.  Yes, invariably the "main window" of an app.  That the WPF project template automatically creates a MainWindow class is not an accident.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant.  I  totally agree. I needed just something to show to somebody and the answer below has MSDN link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/uxguide/winenv-taskbar).

> Make the following window types appear on the taskbar (for Windows 7, by using a taskbar button thumbnail):

- Primary windows (which includes dialog boxes without owners)
- Property sheets
- Modeless progress dialog boxes
- Wizards

> For Windows 7, use taskbar button thumbnails to group the following window types with the primary window taskbar button it was launched from. Each program (specifically, each program perceived as a separate program) should have a single taskbar button.

- Secondary windows
- Workspace tabs
- Project windows
- MDI child windows

Comment: thanks! I knew there was microsoft guidelines about it but i couldn't find it with google.